# Discrete math question - Fibonacci sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Fibonacci sequence is embedded in Pascal’s triangle by investigating
“stretched diagonals”. While this is true, it is not obvious how the sequence is embedded.
Redraw Pascal’s triangle to make it clear how the Fibonacci sequence is embedded in the triangle, and
explain the calculation required to obtain the sequence. A formal proof is not required; an observation
over 12 rows of the triangle will suffice. You may use the fact that the r-th number in the n-th row of
the triangle is C(n; r) when explaining the calculation.

Comment: Hint: Pascal’s triangle does not need to be drawn as an isosceles triangle.

Comment: Questions posted as commands generally don't receive a warm reception. I recommend checking the how-to-ask-questions FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Shear the usual representation of Pascal's triangle by shifting each successive row further to the right.  The Fibonacci numbers can be made to appear as column sums.
$$
\begin{array}{*{9}c}
 1 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    & \\
   &  1 &  1 &    &    &    &    &    & \\
   &    &  1 &  2 &  1 &    &    &    & \\
   &    &    &  1 &  3 &  3 &  1 &    & \\
   &    &    &    &  1 &  4 &  6 &  4 & 1 \\
& & & & & \vdots & \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 
\end{array}
$$